# Forward all traffic through one machine but still allow SSH connection

Tags: networking, ssh, iptables

I currently have multiple machines `M0`,...,`Mn` connected by a switch. Additionally one designated management machine `M0` has an additional NIC which is connected to the outside network (and internet). It looks like this:

```
                    +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+
outside ------------| M0 |  | M1 |  | M2 |  | Mn |
network             +----+  +----+  +----+  +----+
                       |       |      |       |
                       |       |      |       |
                       \      /========\      /
                        \-----| switch |-----/
                              \========/
```

I have working communication between the machines on their own internal network and I can also access outside network from machine `M0`, I can SSH other machines from `M0`.

Now I am trying to get also working Internet connection for the other machines `M1`,...,`Mn`. I don't need this permanent, preferably a temporary switch so that I can do updates or install something on the other machines, whenever needed.

My problem is that whenever I setup IP forwarding, my SSH connection from `M0` (where I am working on) to the other machines gets broken. So I would need to forward all traffic through `M0` but still allow SSH connections between `M0` and any `Mn`.

---

My current approach is that whenever Internet is needed, I set `M0` as the default gateway on that particular machine and update `/etc/resolv.conf`.

On `M0`, the following iptables rules are activated:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.2.0/24       anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.2.0/24      

# NAT table
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.2.0/24       anywhere
```

Is forwarding everything but keeping SSH alive possible to do just with iptables? When I try to reject SSH connections before accepting for forwards, they get -- well, rejected, instead of processed at the machine.

All machines are Ubuntu 16.04.3.

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: You are asking for a specific iptables solution, but would using a proxy service on Machine 0 be feasible?

Comment: I had a similar issue, where I need to allow users to SSH to different machines on the corporate network from outside, controlled "jump box"(Bastian machine). With this approach, I didn't need to IP forward for SSH as I was using `Proxycommand`. But I then hit a whole bunch of dead walls when accessing HTML content. Instead, I end up using OpenVPN server now with TUN network config. Which is much better.

Comment: @Stefan I am not determined to use only iptables (I probably haven't expressed myself clearly there), I am just looking for a clean and simple solution, which is ideally easy to turn on and also off.

Comment: @PraveenP ^ Same applies to your comment.